# send web url + some text to other applications using ACTION_SEND

Tags: android

I need to send some text and a play store url through app chooser. 
This is my code:

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"hi\r\n");
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("www.google.com");
share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml("<a href=\""+myUri+"\">"+myUri+"</a>"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,getResources().getString(R.string.ShareThought)));
```

Even after doing this, i am not able to show the first text(hi) in the choosen app and the link displayed is not clickable, it just got underlined.

I need help in order to send the text and web url together.

Comment: @Prenra Singhal What do you mean it's an implicit intent? so because of that you won't know what is being in the other application

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `putExtra` method twice and therefore overwriting the value it stores.

You should combine both of the extras into the same `putExtra` call. Do this instead:

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("www.google.com");
share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hi\r\n" + myUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, getResources().getString(R.string.ShareThought)));
```

Comment: @Prerna Singhal Can you show the code that you are using to show the URL on the other side? From there I can then tell why it is not becoming clickable...that will be a separate issue.

Comment: Hi edwoollard, I am using gmail option from app to share my content. Also i tried combining bothe the putExtra like you did but then the second text is not getting hyperlinked.

Comment: How are you displaying the URL when it reaches the second application?

Comment: I am selecting the pre  installed apps like gmail, evernote..I need to display my web link in the next line to my text

Comment: @PrernaSinghal I do not think that adding the HTML anchor tags is necessary. Apps like Gmail are set up to receive URLs automatically. I have updated my answer. Please give that a try.